# iPhone Provisioning Question

Tags: iphone, certificate, code-signing, provisioning

I've recently reinstalled OSX, and now, when trying to build a new version of my already active app, I'm running into issues. Firstly it is complaining:

```
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution: Joshua ONeal' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain
```

So, I realized that I deleted my certificates. So I went over to developer.apple.com, and redownloaded the WWDR Certificate, my development certificate, and my distribution certificate. All 3 installed into Keychain with no issues. Now, when I try to download the team development provisioning profile, and the app specific distribution provisioning profile, and install them, they both throw the following error in XCode's organizer:

```
A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain.
```

What gives? Am I missing a certificate? Or, do I have to revoke them at dev.apple and recreate them with my fresh install?

Thanks a lot, this is very confusing, and it is stressing me out that I can't get a bug fix out asap.

UPDATE:

Here is what fixed it for me.

1. Revoke the developer and distributor certificates, as well as the two provisioning profiles.
2. Open Keychain Access, and delete the old certificates.
3. Create 2 new certs, and 2 new prov. profiles, and install them.
4. Open XCode, go to the app's target on the left side, get info, update the two code signing options to use the new certificate.
5. Clean all targets, build and archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need the matching private key to go with your certificates. If you did a fresh OS X install, you will have erased the private key you used to create the initial signing request. The solution is as you suggest to revoke your current certificates and generate new ones with a new signing request.

To avoid this happening in the future, you can export the private keys you create in Keychain and back them up somewhere to use in the future if you want to develop on a new computer or fresh install.

Comment: Just to clarify, I need to revoke, delete, and regenerate the 2 (dist & dev) certs and reinstall them right? Do I need to touch the WWDR cert or the two provisioning profiles?

Comment: Once you've regenerated your certificates, you'll need to re-download your provisioning profiles (provisioning profiles are linked to certificates). You will need to make a change (any change) to your provisioning profiles to get them to use your new certificates. Normally for me this is as simple as adding or removing a device from them.

Comment: I got it! I had to update the code signing flag under the build tab of the app, as well as resupply my other linker flags and header search paths. Thank you so much!